# How can I get path to my files on device?

Tags: android, path

How can I get path where my application is installed so I can access to raw folder and set some file as ringtone?

```
String path=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "sdcard/data/FunnySoundsz/res/raw/fusrodah.mp3";
```

But nothing happens with this. I set in my Manifest that app install only on Internal Storage

Comment: And when you print out the full path it looks like? 
Do you have permission to access the external Storage? ( you sure there is not a `/` missing before sdcard? )

Comment: Um, which permission is that?
I got   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: That is good enough yes. There is definately a `/` missing before `sdcard`. And I assume you are trying to access a second sdcard? Else externalStrorageDirectory should already include the `sdcard` bit.

Comment: Added `/` still same.

Comment: Try removing sdcard too. Plus, find out the full path. And you should see the issue.

Comment: Ok so I removed sdcard now it's looking like this: `String path=android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + "/data/FunnySoundsz/res/raw/fusrodah.mp3";`
But still app can't set it as ringtone

Comment: But what does `path` actually equal?? What is the full string. `Log.i("OUTPUT", path);`

Comment: It's for Ringtone manager. I need to chose which file to set as ringtone when clicking on some button. 
here is logcat: `02-14 17:10:19.994: I/OUTPUT(8829): /storage/sdcard0/data/FunnySoundsz/res/raw/fusrodah.mp3
`

Comment: That looks better than what you had before. Try browsing to that location your phone. does it exist? Also, code using `File.exists()` to see if it thinks so. It sounds like you are unable to find the right file. Is there an error log? Im signing out for the day, but hopefully someone else could help if you provide more info

Comment: Um yeah File exists, I can find it while browsing on PC but when I try to find it with file explorer on device, I can't see it. No errors are shown